# Overriding Django Admin's main page? - Django

Tags: python, django, admin, overriding

I'm trying to add features to **Django 1.2** admin's main page.

I've been playing with index.html, but features added to this page affect all app pages.

---

Any ideas on what template I'm supposed to use?

Thanks loads!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use template hierarchy like:

**index.html**

```
...
{% block content %}
...
{% block mycontent %}My custom text{% endblock %}
...
{% endblock %}
```

**app_index.html**

```
...
    {% block mycontent %}{% endblock %}
..
```

Answer (score 3):

I have done this by modifying the `admin/index.html` template. You may also need to modify `admin/base_site.html` (depending on what you want to do, exactly).

These templates are found in the `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin` folder in a Django installation.

**Update:** That's exactly what I've done, see the screenshot fragment below. The section marked in red is the section I added, via HTML in `admin/index.html`. However, you don't say which version of Django you're using - my example is from a 1.0 installation.

[image: Screenshot of customised admin page]

Comment: thanks for the reply. I already override all those templates, but I just wish to add html to the "home" page, the page where all the apps and their models are listed

Comment: thank you so much for your great reply! I'm using Django 1.2, overriding index.html works nicely, but all App Indexes get overridden. I might have done something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

According to http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template you will want to override admin/app_index.html